# Bash Scripting homework assignment

Tags: shell

> Write a script to help users calculate their tax returns. Prompt the
>   user to enter his/her income from keyboard, Then us the following
>   rules for calculation. Display the results on the screen.
>
> - If the income is less than 5000, no tax
> - If the income is between 5000 and 30000, the tax rate is 10%
> - If the income is more tan 30000, the tax rate is 20%

Here is my attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter your income tax:" $var1
if [[ $var1 -lt 5000 ]];
then
 echo "no tax"
elif [[ $var1 -gt 5000 && $var1 -lt 30000 ]];
then
 echo "the tax rate is 10%"
else
 if [[ $var1 -gt 30000 ]];
then 
echo "the tax rate is 20%"
 fi
fi
```

Now, when I run the program, no matter what number I put in there it will always says no tax. Can someone tell my what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Change the $var1 in your read statement to just var1

Comment: when I did that now nothing is coming up. it just accepted it and the program was done.

Comment: then why is my program not working then? I am still confused because my logic is there, I don't know what else could be wrong.

Comment: @user1221394  Did you change all occurrences of var1, or just the one in the read statement?  You should only change it in the read statement.

Comment: I figured out what I did. You were right William Pursell, I did accidentally change one of the var1, and now it works thank you guys soooo much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter your income: "
read income

if [ $income -lt 5000 ]
then echo "no tax for you"
fi

if [ $income -ge 5000 -a $income -le 30000 ]
then echo "Your tax rate is 10%"
fi

if [ $income -gt 30000 ]
then echo "Your tax rate is 20%"
fi
```

I looked at your solution and think it is a problem with your if/else statements. The structure should always be if-elif-else. But you have an if statement after your else? Also, with bash you don't necessarily have to use elif for a second if statement like in a functional language like Haskell. So you can simply do three if statements.

Comment: They didn't specify exclusive or not, but it makes since so I changed the middle if from gt and lt to ge and le

Answer (score 0):

```
read -p "Enter your income tax:" var1
if [[ $var1 -lt 5000 ]];
then
 echo "no tax"
elif [[ $var1 -gt 5000 && $var1 -lt 30000 ]];
then
 echo "the tax rate is 10%"
else
 if [[ $var1 -gt 30000 ]];
then 
echo "the tax rate is 20%"
 fi
fi
```

It runs fine. (prog.sh be the file having this source).

```
$ sh prog.sh
Enter your income tax:6000
no tax

$ sh prog.sh
Enter your income tax:6000
the tax rate is 10%

$ sh prog.sh
Enter your income tax:40000
the tax rate is 20%
```

Comment: If the income is exactly 5000, or exactly 30000, there is no output.